# How to load mongodb databases with special character in their names in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, dataframe

I'm trying to import the mongodb collection data in a pandas dataframe. When the database name is simple like 'admin', it's able to load in the dataframe. However when I try with one of my required databases named asdev-Admin (line 5), I get an empty dataframe. Apparently the error's somewhere related to the special character in the db name, but I don't know how to get around it. How do I resolve this??

```
import pymongo
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.asdev-Admin
collection = db.system.groups
data = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find()))
print(data)
```

The error states: NameError: name 'Admin' is not defined

Comment: I think you need to add MongoDB URL to connect in `client = MongoClient(URL)`

Comment: No, that's working fine, it's messing up with the special character (-) in the database name asdev-Admin, since it's filling the dataframe correctly with another database named 'admin'. Any way with which I could probably utilize the (-), so it would not create problem in db = client.asdev-Admin would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `db = client.asdev-Admin` to `db = client['asdev-Admin']`.

Comment: Yea, worked like a charm, this is what I was looking for. It was so silly yet been disturbing me for a large part of the day. Thanks!!